# Let tmux set urxvt window title according to session-name

Tags: unix, tmux, urxvt

Everyday I launch a bunch of `urxvtc -e tmux`.

I am trying to find a way to override urxvt X window title ("tmux") with the current tmux session name set via `:rename-session session_name`.

Does any of you guys achieved that ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding the following to your ~/.tmux.conf file.

```
# Turn on window titles
set -g set-titles on

# Set window title string
#  #H  Hostname of local host
#  #I  Current window index
#  #P  Current pane index
#  #S  Session name
#  #T  Current window title
#  #W  Current window name
#  #   A literal ‘#’
set -g set-titles-string '#S:#I.#P #W'

# Automatically set window title
setw -g automatic-rename
```

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to be enough. It keeps displaying this boring "tmux".

Comment: Ok, thanks having put me on the correct way. 
You first need to `set -g set-titles on`. Then you can customize the `set-titles-string` if you like.

Comment: To be clear, if you include this to your answer I'll accept it, for posterity :).

Comment: okay - I updated my answer and added some info on the character sequences